# Why the Weight parameters don't work on Android 5.1.1?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I have created a GridLayout with 3 rows and 3 columns, I have populated it with 9 imageViews like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="eu.isisbassafriulana.android.tria.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Inizia una nuova partita"
        android:onClick="onStart"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android"
            android:onClick="cellPressed"/>
    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a smartphone (Xiaomi Redmi 2 Pro 2014813) with Android 5.1.1 and API 22 with firmware MIUI. When I compile the project, on my smartphone I can't see the images because seems that the weight parameters doesn't work.
On the left there is a screenshot of my smartphone, on the right the Android Studio Preview
[image: Smartphone vs IDE]

Comment: You set the weights, but not the positions of your cells.

Comment: And what if you remove `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"`?

Comment: Resolved, I have to insert                                       android:layout_gravity="fill"